# Xamarin Forms Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics SSL issues

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I recently started using Microsoft AppCenter for crash reporting and analytics in my Xamarin forms app. Following the instructions, I added the Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics and Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes packages to my Shared, IOS and Android projects. Both iOS and Android are showing SSL errors in the application output, and don't appear to be reporting data on actual devices. Simulators do seem to be logging analytics data, but not crash data.

**Android**

```
[AppCenter] Try #1 failed and will be retried in 5657 ms
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.internal.ht10-22 11:35:51.380 W/AppCenter(14545): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xd2ee5600: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
[AppCenter]     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:201)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:155)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
[AppCenter]     at com.microsoft.appcenter.tp.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
[AppCenter]     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
[AppCenter]     at com.microsoft.appcenter.http.DefaultHttpClientCallTask.doHttpCall(DefaultHttpClientCallTask.java:226)
[AppCenter]     at com.microsoft.appcenter.http.DefaultHttpClientCallTask.doInBackground(DefaultHttpClientCallTask.java:279)
[AppCenter]     at com.microsoft.appcenter.http.DefaultHttpClientCallTask.doInBackground(DefaultHttpClientCallTask.java:48)
[AppCenter]     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
[AppCenter]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
[AppCenter]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
[AppCenter]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
[AppCenter]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

IOS

```
2021-10-22 22:39:23.683347-0400 BehaviorLive.iOS[42811:1307421] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics
2021-10-22 22:39:29.865443-0400 BehaviorLive.iOS[42811:1307420] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics
```

Comment: Hi! This looks like a network issue. Unfortunately, sometimes it happens.
I can suggest you try to change the DNS settings on your phone or try to switch to another network connection (for example turn off Wi-Fi and turn on mobile data instead) or use VPN.   
Also, sometimes it happens due to country specific policies and laws. Please see this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/app-center-security#data-residency-and-sovereignty).    
But anyway all logs in this case will be rescheduled and when the connection will be established then all logs will be sent.

Comment: Yea, this appears to have gone away. Very strange.